# CSV_NON_TRIMABLE_CHAR_AFTER_CLOSING_QUOTE csv parse for node?

Tags: node.js, csv, parsing, amazon-redshift, node-csv-parse

I'm using a 3rd party application that throws this error:

```
Error: Invalid Closing Quote: found non trimable byte after quote at line 5
code:                 CSV_NON_TRIMABLE_CHAR_AFTER_CLOSING_QUOTE
column:               16
empty_lines:          0
header:               false
index:                16
invalid_field_length: 0
quoting:              true
lines:                5
records:              4
```

when loading a csv file (I have to use this application). I think this application is using this node service: https://csv.js.org/parse/errors/

I also think the trouble is that column 16 has fields that look like this:

```
\Circular Logic 3\""
```

But I don't quite understand the issue.

Can anyone tell me if this column is not escaping the quotes properly? I have a ton of files and many instances like this in column 16 so it would be a pain to fix this manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like proper escaping for double quotes in csv is another double quote. So the line should be:

```
\Circular Logic 3"""
```

We'll have to reformat the data.